# Windows Phone 8.1 XAML App. How to prevent inappropriate automatic focus change?

Tags: c#, xaml, focus, windows-phone-8.1

Imagine the following simple page markup:

```
<Page
    x:Class="AutoFocusBug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <StackPanel>
        <!--<Button x:Name="FocusHolder" Width="0" Height="0" MinHeight="0" MinWidth="0"/>-->
        <TextBox Text="zxczczczczx"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

and the following code-behind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

When I click `Button1` button it hides (which is expected and desired) but for some reason `TextBox` automatically gets focus and on-screen keyboard appears. I don't want this unexpected auto-focus.

I can try to do something with focus in `Click` handler but in real app it is implemented with ViewModel with commands and so on and it looks like dirty hack (and also keyboard appears for short period even if I change focus immediately after hiding button).

The second approach I found is to create "invisible" button somewhere before the textbox (commented `FocusHolder`) which is quite better but also doesn't look like correct technique.

So, what is that? Is this some mechanism that I can somehow configure to "redirect" focus from collapsed element? Or is it a bug? What is the right way to prevent this undesired auto-focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is due to to the `Tab` index switching from the button to the Textbox. This is a very annoying thing of WP8.1. I have not found a "good" solution for this, but this might be cleaner than your current solution.

The xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="zxczczczczx"/>
```

The function

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.IsTabStop = false;
    Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    myTextBox.IsTabStop = true;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for another solution. "Invisible" button is still the best solution in my case, but it is good to have more options. Does not seem that there is a correct solution, so I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by setting the TabIndex.

Set the index order to focus on your second control before the TextBox.

```
<Page
x:Class="AutoFocusBug.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<StackPanel>
    <!--<Button x:Name="FocusHolder" Width="0" Height="0" MinHeight="0" MinWidth="0"/>-->
    <TextBox Text="zxczczczczx" TabIndex="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" TabIndex="1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set TabNavigation="Cycle" to the Button. This is working for me.